# Place div on image but responsive

Tags: html, css

I have an image with some circles on hands fingers in the image. I am placing glowing div on the image.

```
{
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    margin: 0 !important;
    padding: 0 !important;
}
```

This is how I place glowing circle.

```
.small_rings_group {
    position: absolute;
    left: 25.3vw;
    top: 10vh;
}
```

Its works perfect on window width change but when I change the height of the window, the placement changed.

[image: screen Shot]

Comment: can you show us a link to the site or a complete code ? so we can reproduce

Comment: http://frt.muffrank.com/ goto the second slide and change the height of the browser window @TemaniAfif

Comment: i would say it's a bit impossible as your slider is moving even when you reduce the width, so you cannot use fixed values ... maybe JS solution will be good, but it will hard to code

Comment: I also see it's layer slider plugin, i made similare thing but with Revo Slider. because Revo slider will scale the whole slide so everything stay in place

Comment: I think I have to detect objects from image?? I can do this but that is last option for me. Are there any possibilities with the CSS?

Comment: no way with CSS as you cannot use the slide image as reference to define the values, you have different layers

Comment: Hmm Thanks @TemaniAfif I will use object detection. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

1.) Use `position: relative` for the image to have it act as "position anchor" for the absolutely positioned elements.

2.) In the CSS of the absolutely positioned elements, don't use absolute values, but percentage values for left and top (will be in relation to the parent). This will keep the position responsive.

Comment: Even I suggest to try this.